# Activities Component showing for all users in the same profile & role except for one user

Tags: page-layout, tasks, activity, activity-settings

For some weird reason, all users with the SAME Role & SAME Profile can see the Activities component EXCEPT for one user in that role & profile as below:

[image: Activities Component]

I have checked the Page Layouts are all configured with the `Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions` with those actions e.g. New Task, New Event, Log a Call, Email.

Why is this user so special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours searching and debugging why this special case. Figured out it is because that "Special" user decided to change his settings as below :

So to ensure Activities components appears for all users you also need to do

```
Personal Settings > Record Page Settings > Activity Timeline
```

[image: Record Page Settings]